# Array optimization: what is more expensive?

Tags: ruby, arrays, optimization

Which of the following pieces of code is more expensive?

```
x = my_array.inject {|sum,i| int+=i }
```

or

```
x = eval(my_array.join('+'))
```

Comment: It's very creative to use the second method:)

Comment: +1 for second option, but you can also do my_array.sum

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try them:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w
require 'benchmark'
iterations = 1000000

Benchmark.bmbm do |bench|
  numbers = (1..100).to_a

  bench.report('inject') do
    x = numbers.inject { |sum, num| sum + num }
  end
  bench.report('eval') do
    x = eval(numbers.join('+'))
  end
end
```

Which gives:

```
telemachus ~ $ ruby bench.rb 
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------
inject   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000029)
eval     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000261)
--------------------------------- total: 0.000000sec

             user     system      total        real
inject   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000047)
eval     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000186)
```

But actually, I think you're micro-optimizing. I would use `inject` unless it was grossly inefficient, since it's what the method was built for.

Also I think that your code for `inject` has two issues. First, you don't mean `int`, you mean `sum`. Second, you can simply add the items, rather than use `+=`. The first paramter to `inject` automatically accumulates value.

Comment: eval is gonna be far slower due to the nauture of it, avoid it when you can.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of a thumb, *eval* code is always slower than its reasonable eval-free alternative (as in this case). It's also potentially insecure if it processes user input.

And just for the record, in Rails (or after `require 'activeresource'`) you can also use `numbers.sum` method, which is roughly as fast as *inject* and IMHO more readable.